# What is the use of testing_additional_tests.txt defined in testing.xml in Hybris?

Tags: java, junit, build, sap-commerce-cloud

What is the use of file `testing_additional_tests.txt` defined in

> hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/testing.xml?

The code to access this file is pretty useless as well. First, it is deleted and then it is accessed!

```
<delete file="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}/testing_additional_tests.txt"/>
            <trycatch property="foo" reference="bar">
                <try>
                    <echoxml file="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}/testing_additional_tests.txt" append="true">
                        <additionalTests/>
                    </echoxml>
                </try>
                <catch/>
            </trycatch>

            <loadfile property="additional.tests" srcFile="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}/testing_additional_tests.txt"/>
```

Comment: I had a problem with the `testing_additional_tests.txt` file when I used `ant 10` to build a project on hybris, when I installed `ant 9` the problem went away

Comment: yep, probably you forgot to run "setantenv.bat" and somewhere else in path you have non hybris ant